# image in excel report

Tags: image, report, odoo, xlsx

Help, How can i print image excel report?
Please, help me?
I use xlsxwriter. 
[Example of xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images_bytesio.html)
This is my code:

```
product_image = product_product.product_tmpl_id.image
imgdata = base64.b64decode(product_image)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
# imgdata = base64.b64decode(product_image)
# image =  io.BytesIO(imgdata)
print type(image)
sheet.insert_image(rowx, 12, str(image))
```

The error is:

```
warn("Image file '%s' not found." % force_unicode(filename))
```

How to solve?
My goal is print product image in odoo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
product_image = product_product.product_tmpl_id.image
imgdata = base64.b64decode(product_image)
image = io.BytesIO(imgdata)

worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'myimage.png', {'image_data': image})
```

See the [insert_image()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#insert_image) section of the XlsxWriter docs and this [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images_bytesio.html#ex-images-bytesio) of inserting images from an `io.BytesIO` byte stream into a worksheet.

Comment: great to know it, I have done it before using openpyxl, but I haven't known about that xlswriter could do it too, passing image_data option