# How to insert an image to an excel file with xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, django, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I have to write images with some other datas to an excel file in my Django project and I have tried the code below.

```
for counter_i, cost in enumerate(costs):
        counter_i += 1
        for counter_j, feature in enumerate(features):
            value = getattr(cost, feature)
            if feature == 'image':
                image = str(value)
                worksheet.insert_image(counter_i, counter_j, image, {'x_offset': 15, 'y_offset': 10})
            else:
                worksheet.write(counter_i, counter_j, value)
```

In this code, the "value" contains image's path. But I got errors such as

`warn("Image file '%s' not found." % force_unicode(filename))`

Also I have tried to give the whole path such as `C:/Users/username/..` but this time, I got an `Permission Denied` error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on adding images using xlsxwriter. But found few useful links which has similar issue and some information related to the same.

[This_link_if_you_are_using_URL](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images_bytesio.html)

[Image_with_path](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#insert_image)

[Similar_issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148963/image-in-excel-report)

Comment: I have looked at the 'similar_issue' link and tried that but still got the same error "Permission Denied"

Comment: The code that in 'similar_issue' works. The problem was the image format. JPG should not be used. Thank you!!